# Never ending query

Tags: sql, oracle

My query worked fine up to this day.

I suppose there is some problem with index.

Note: On column type (in table_1) there is index, and type is not unique in table_1

Here is what query looks alike:

```
--works fine(finish in 5 seconds)
select *
from table_1 a,table_2 b
where a.id=b.id
and a.date < date'2014-6-31'
and a.type=2
```

When I increase date range (include 1 month more, thats about 1000 records more) it doesn't finish, so I have to stop it.

```
--never ending
select *
from table_1 a,table_2 b
where a.id=b.id
and a.date < date'2014-7-31'
and a.type=2
```

But when I omit column that has index, it's ok:

```
--works fine
select *
from table_1 a,table_2 b
where a.id=b.id
and a.date < date'2014-7-31'
```

I would be grateful on any hint.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the statistics and the index? (Don't do this right off the bat if it's a production system and there's millions of rows because you'll cause downtime)

Comment: No I haven't. I don't have privileges to do that. I will ask database admin to do that tomorrow.

Comment: You could also look at the execution plan in SSMS to see what's taking the time

Comment: I forget to mention: For query that is not ending it shows cost about 30000 and for one below it about 130000 (which is logicaly ok, since in never ending query there is extra condition - a.type=2)

Comment: @Gareth SSMS...? SQL Server Management Studio? But this is Oracle? *confused*

Comment: @jpmc26 my bad. Overlooked the oracle tag. I assume you can view execution plans in Oracle?

Comment: @Gareth Yes, but how easily depends on your tool. SQL Developer makes it relatively painless; there's a button (with keyboard shortcut). Trying to do it from SQL*Plus (command line) involves running some command and then fetching it from some weird table. I imagine the other decent tools also offer a button or something.

Comment: You just have to stop "the nothing" from spreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to  disable index this way:

```
ALTER INDEX idxname DISABLE;
```

You can also rebuild index

```
ALTER INDEX idxname REBUILD;
```

or gather statistics on the table

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('yourschema', 'table');
```

But be careful it could take long time!

Comment: Problem solved.

We just had to re-analize partition for august in table_1.

It's statistics was not up to date, so execution plan was not appropriate, and that caused query to last more than expected.

Thank you on your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query plan to see what's happened.

Before you runstats or disable index, recode the query plan first, compare the query plan after runstats or disable index. Then you can figure out what's happened in your database by your self.

You should know, not all index helps.

Some times without index, dbms will choose full table scan and hash join to improve the performance.

But with some index, dbms may use next loop join, this type of join may cause less cost, but may execute serial.